# What are the use cases for a certification PGP subkey?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, openpgp

What are the use cases for a certification only PGP subkey?
I am not sure if GnuPG supports it but I know [Sequoia](https://sequoia-pgp.org/) does.

Comment: GPG supports it, with it generally being recommended to create a main pirmary key only able to [S]ign and [C]ertify keys only, using subkeys for [A]uthentication, [E]ncryption, and Digital [S]igning. I don't have the time to write an answer, but the `gpg` [man page](https://gnupg.org/documentation/index.html) documentation covers this thoroughly as does a google search.

Comment: I don't know what kind of google search you did but I could not find anything about certification subkeys anywhere, only encryption and/or signing subkeys.

Comment: I'm not on my PC at the moment to review what search terms I used, however their man page covers it in detail

Comment: Is your question mainly about what a "certification" key does in general (it's a baseline PGP feature), or are you asking specifically about using a *sub*key for certification as opposed to the main key?

Comment: I am asking about using a subkey for certification

Comment: @dblouis, @JW0914 : According to that detailed answer, certification subkeys are not possible with PGP : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42492/can-a-pgp-subordinate-key-be-used-as-a-web-of-trust-signing-key. And I couldn't find any single source that say it is. https://docs.kernel.org/6.1/process/maintainer-pgp-guide.html talks about "certification subkey", but I think they use that term to describe the `[SCA]` primary key.

Comment: @ChennyStar Please re-read my comment - the main _primary_ key should be SC, used to sign and certify _subkeys_.

Comment: @JW0914 - yes, so we do agree : PGP (and thus GnuPG) DOES NOT support certification subkeys. Only the master key can have `[C]` capabilities.